# Changes in Android Studio's project gradle file

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have recently updated my Android Studio to latest version. But the gradle file here seems bit different.

here is the gradle code :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

I want to add these below jitsi lines in the project gradle file. how should I paste it so that it syncs properly without any errors.

here is the jitsi code :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the gradle file by adding or replacing the above lines, Nothing changes. It is throwing an error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It is related to gradle sync fail error. It says could not compile build file "only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed".  And If am just adding jitsi dependency in app gradle it says "Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.0.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you appear to be using the [recently revised build configuration scripts](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases#expandable-8), you should be able to declare your repositories under the [`settings.gradle` file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#settings-file):

```
pluginManagement {
    // Plugin repositories go here
}
// ...
dependencyResolutionManagement {

    /**
     * The dependencyResolutionManagement {repositories {...}}
     * block is where you configure the repositories and dependencies used by
     * all modules in your project, such as libraries that you are using to
     * create your application. However, you should configure module-specific
     * dependencies in each module-level build.gradle file. For new projects,
     * Android Studio includes Google's Maven repository and the Maven Central
     * Repository by default, but it does not configure any dependencies (unless
     * you select a template that requires some).
     */

    // The following line makes it so that project modules (such as your
    // "app" module) can't declare their own repositories {} block
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Add your repositories here...
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

---

> only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

As for this error, this is because `plugins` blocks are always resolved *first*, and so any other code must be declared *after* that block:

```
// There shouldn't be any code before this!
plugins {

}
// Okay to have build script code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio latest version you move the jitsi repository in the project's settings.gradle file

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
}
```